# Is it possible to combine a Wordpress template (Semplice) and some HTML & CSS pages?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, templates

I am developing a portfolio website for a client. I started using [Semplice](https://www.semplice.com/), a WordPress template/editor that allows you to create portfolio websites more easily.

The thing is that I want to add my own page for the home. As Semplice won't allow you to modify everything so precisely, I decided to create myself an `index.html` with some CSS and JavaScript.

But I don't know if this is possible. I mean, I want to have my own index (home) created by me, and I want the other sections to work through WordPress with the Semplice template.

So basically, there are 4 sections: Home, Work, Feed and Info.

I want to use the Home page that I designed, but for the Work, Feed and Info sections (everything but the home page), I want to use WordPress + Semplice.

Do you know if this is possible?
I guess it is, but I don't really know how to do it. Please, help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not optimal but possible.

you simply need to use your index.html html page and in the main menu of your index.html page you link to the permalinks of your wordpress website. I would put the wordpress website in a subfolder like www.url.com/wordpress for instance.

In the wordpress website you need to add a home element in the main menu pointing to the index.html page of your html  website (www.url.com).

For instance, the menu of your HTML page would look like this (considering your use bootstrap for css):

```
<nav id="menu1" class="bar bar--sm bar-1 hidden-xs bar--absolute bar--transparent">
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2 hidden-xs">
                  <div class="bar__module">
                      <a href="./index.html">

                          <img class="logo logo-light" alt="logo" src="images/logo.png" />
                      </a>
                  </div>
                  <!--end module-->
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-11 col-md-12 text-right text-left-xs text-left-sm">
                  <div class="bar__module">
                      <ul class="menu-horizontal text-left">
                          <li>
                              <a href="www.url.com/index.html">
                                  HOME
                              </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                              <a href="www.url.com/wordpress/permalinkpagework">
                                  WORK
                              </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                              <a href="www.url.com/wordpress/permalinkpagefeed">
                                  WORK
                              </a>
                          </li>
                          <li>
                              <a href="www.url.com/wordpress/permalinkpageinfo">
                                  WORK
                              </a>
                          </li>



                      </ul>
                  </div>

              </div>
          </div>
          <!--end of row-->
      </div>
      <!--end of container-->
    </nav>
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a quite common thing to do in Wordpress websites, and WordPress comes with built in support for just these kinds of situations.

What you need to do is to create a `page` in WordPress and add a custom template file for that page. Then in WordPress' reading settings, you select that page as the front page for the website.

Now don't worry, you don't need to master PHP to pull this off, it's really quite simple. I will walk you through it.

**Step 1:**

Create a `page` in WordPress and give it a slug like `custom-top` or something else you think fits. Publish this page and make sure that it's public.

**Step 2:**

Create a file in your themes top directory called `page-custom-top.php`. WordPress will know automagically that the page `custom-top` should use this template file.

**Step 3:**

Inside `page-custom-top.php` You add your HTML.

**Step 4:**

Go to Settings->Reading in the WordPress admin area, and at `Your homepage displays` you select `A static page` and select the page you made in the `Homepage` drop down menu.
Save the settings.

Now your WordPress top page should display your HTML.

**EDIT:**

You have an additional benefit in doing this as it gives you the ability to access all WordPress variables, functions, template tags etc, should you ever wish to pimp your HTML file with some dynamic content via PHP.

You don't have to, but it might be something you'd want to learn more about in the future.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-tags/

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/